# Is there an expand() method for java?

Tags: java

This is just a general question!
For an assignment my teacher gave, she worded this as "Almost all shapes are Expandable, meaning all dimensions can be increased by a (multiplicative) factor such as 2 (which would make the shape twice as large in all directions) by invoking method expand()." 
I tried googling the expand() method and couldn't really find anything so I was wondering, is there an expand method that is the in the object class that everything can use? Or do I have to make one myself?

Comment: I think you misunderstood some part of the surrounding context. It sounds like a theoretical example -- Java's `Shape` type doesn't have any `expand` method.

Comment: Your teacher is telling you that you should implement this method on your own (presumeably in some _Shape_ class that **you** will implement).  Don't expect to find it anywhere... Especially in `java.lang.Object`.  Such a method would be applicable to a very small percentage of the classes that already exist (as hexafraction has pointed out).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no `expand(` method in the Object class, as it semantically isn't useful for (almost) all objects. Imagine trying to `expand(` a socket or write binary data to a hexagon, for example. In addition expand may mean different things. For a shape, one thing. For compressed binary data, another.

You may look into creating your own method(as an instance method of your shape class) or via something more advanced like [`AffineTransform`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/geom/AffineTransform.html) that can be applied to `java.awt.geom` shape classes.

Edit after re-read: Your teacher may have created a class for you to use. Or, being an assignment, making an expandable shape is your goal.

Comment: @user2762979 No problem! Once you can, please click the checkmark next to my answer if it helped. In about a second it should turn green, and the answer will be marked as solving your question.

Comment: I most certainly was going to! :) It's making me wait 8 more minutes! haha!